# Sort products based taxonomy

Tags: sorting

I have two different brand products on category, but would like to separate them based taxonomy. Like... taxonomy is brand and answers are apple and samsung. How could I make that products with taxonomy brand:apple appear first.

Comment: Can you share some code, or maybe elaborate a bit more on what exactly you want? What programming language are you using? Please add more information.

Comment: Hey, thanks! 
Sorry, but I do not have any code. 
Have a look-> https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1suP8DLmHnl9yMfKXYmkO0JOfvSTu6M4b?usp=sharing.
Platform wordpress, woocommerce and theme flatsome.